# Authorize if not in specific role attribute MVC 5

Tags: attributes, authorization, asp.net-mvc-5

I need authorization attribute for action which allows all but specific role.
something like

```
    [!Authorize(Roles = "SuperUser")]
    public ActionResult PaySuperUser.....
```

Anything built in?
Or any suggestion for custom attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a custom attribute is a way to go.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

namespace YourFancyNamespace
{
    public class AuthorizeExtended : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private string _notInRoles;
        private List<string> _notInRolesList;

        public string NotInRoles
        {
            get
            {
                return _notInRoles ?? string.Empty;
            }
            set
            {
                _notInRoles = value;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_notInRoles))
                {
                    _notInRolesList = _notInRoles
                        .Split(new[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(r => r.Trim()).ToList();
                }
            }
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
            if (_notInRolesList != null && _notInRolesList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var role in _notInRolesList)
                {
                    if (actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.IsInRole(role))
                    {
                        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how you can use it:

// A AuthorizeExtended equals Authorize(with Role filter) + exclude all pesky users

```
[AuthorizeExtended(Roles = "User", NotInRoles="PeskyUser")]
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Important/DoNotForgetToUpvote")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoNotForgetToUpvote()
{
    return Ok("I did it!");
}
```

// Б AuthorizeExtended equals plain Authorize + exclude all pesky users

```
[AuthorizeExtended(NotInRoles="PeskyUser")]
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Important/DoNotForgetToUpvote")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoNotForgetToUpvote()
{
    return Ok("I did it!");
}
```

// В AuthorizeExtended equals Authorize

```
[AuthorizeExtended]
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Important/DoNotForgetToUpvote")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoNotForgetToUpvote()
{
    return Ok("I did it!");
}
```